# unique of column with unhashable type

Tags: python, pandas

Two out of three of my columns respond fine to `.nunique()`

```
print(df.Column1.nunique())
>>> 45
print(df.Column2.nunique())
>>> 23
```

But the other column:

```
print(df.Column3.nunique())
```

..gives a Traceback, with the following last two lines:

```
pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.unique (pandas/hashtable.c:14999)()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'RequestsCookieJar'
```

When you look at the df in Jupyter, you can to some extent visually see differences between cookies, one might start like this:

```
[<Cookie 1P_JAR=2018-03-07-09
```

..the other like this:

```
[<Cookie 1P_JAR=2018-03-07-08
```

Is there a quick fix so it can tell you how many of them are unique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems need:

```
print(df.Column3.astype(str).nunique())
```

Or:

```
print(df.Column3.apply(tuple).nunique())
```